# How to write integration test for systems that interact asynchronously

Tags: integration-testing

Assume that i have function called `PlaceOrder`, which when called inserts the order details into local DB and puts a message(order details) into a TIBCO EMS Queue.

Once message received, a TIBCO BW will then invoke some other system(say `ExternalSystem`) to pass on the order details.

Now the way i wrote my integration tests is

1. Call the Place Order
2. Sleep, and check details exists in local DB
3. Sleep and check details exists in ExternalSystem.

Is the above approach correct? Above test gives me confidence that, End to End integration is working, but are there any better way to test above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is quite common, and your approach is a very typical solution.

The problem with this solution is that if the delay is too short, your tests may sometimes pass and sometimes fail, but if the delay is very long, then your just wasteing time waiting, and with many tests, it can add a lot of delay. But unless you can get some signal to tell you the order arrived in the database, then you just have to wait.

You can reduce the delay by doing lots of checks with short intervals. If you're order is not there after timeout, then you would fail the test.

In "Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests"*, there is a chapter on this very subject, so you might want to get a copy if you will be doing a lot of this sort of testing.

> "There are two ways a test can observe the system: by sampling its observable
>   state or by listening for events that it sends out. Of these, sampling is
>   often the only option because many systems don’t send any monitoring
>   events. It’s quite common for a test to include both techniques to interact
>   with different “ends” of its system"

(*) http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/software-testing/9780321574442